# Sticky Footer in Chat hiding Information

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

**Please Note: I've blurred out the wording within the images as these snapshots are taken from the new Mentor Experiment.**

I've noticed while using the chat, as a chat begins to receive a lot of 'starred' posts it begins to push the **Enable Desktop Notifications** button out of view as well as other starred posts, these then become unreachable via scrolling.

So on first view:

[image: Example 1]

You can see that half of the Enable Desktop Notifications button is hidden behind the footer.

Then if I click on **show more** to view more starred posts it will push the starred posts as well as the Enable Desktop Notifications button behind the sticky footer:

[image: Example 2]

It is not until I then click **show only top 4** that the view will actually go back to what it is supposed to look like:

[image: Example 3]

My Viewport resolution is: 1280 × 633

I'm using a MacBook Pro 13 Inch

Using Firefox.

Comment: [*"Those stars weren’t so big. They were really so small. You might think such a thing wouldn’t matter at all."*](http://www.barnabasministry.com/quotes-sneeches.html)

Comment: What is your viewport resolution? Stack Exchange sites are not built with responsive web design, so if you are using a resolution that's too small, you will miss out on content.

Comment: Oops. Should have included that. Updated my question @TylerH - I am using quite a small screen.

Comment: @Lag In that case, this might be tagged as [meta-tag:status-bydesign], I'm afraid :-/

Comment: ah... what a pain @TylerH ! In most chats I'd say this doesn't matter.. but in the mentor chat they have a lot of helpful and quick links to be used. Bit of a pain to keep clicking through to all the starred posts. Oh well ! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Lag I would love for them to redesign chat and improve the layout and add functionality, but it's not a priority for them, and the CEO even said chat was a stupid feature on one of their podcasts a while back, so I doubt it will get much attention any time soon.

Comment: @TylerH, it may be a stupid feature to some communities, but to Puzzling and a few others, it is pretty important.